# pgfplot - how to make horizontal error bars

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I would like to add horizontal error bars to my plot, pictured below.
[image]
The code that generates the above plot is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=1, every node/.style={transform shape},trim axis left, trim axis right]
\pgfplotsset{width=16cm,
    compat=1.3,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={ $1/r^2$[\SI{}{1\per\centi\square\meter}]},
ylabel={$i$[\SI{}{\micro\ampere}]},
%extra x ticks={3.5},
%extra tick style={grid=major,major grid style={red,thick},
%tick label style={
%rotate=90,anchor=east}},
%extra x tick labels={Actual},
legend cell align=left,
legend pos=north west],
\addplot[only marks,
        error bars/.cd,
            y dir=both,
            y explicit,
            every nth mark=1
    ] table[x=X,y=Y,y error=Z]{
    X Y Z
0.01000 56.0    2
0.008264    41.0    3
0.006944    31.0    4
0.005917    24.0    5
0.005102    19.0    6
0.004444    15.5    7
0.003906    12.5    9
0.003460    10.5    9
0.003086    9.0     3
0.002770    8.0     2
};
\addlegendentry{Punkty pomiarowe} %
 %\draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
```

And  the function that creates the error bars is:

```
\newcounter{marknumber}
\pgfplotsset{
error bars/every nth mark/.style={
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.prefix code={
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\marknumbercheck{mod(floor(\themarknumber/2),#1)}
        \ifnum\marknumbercheck=0
        \else
            \begin{scope}[opacity=0]
        \fi
    },
    /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.append code={
        \ifnum\marknumbercheck=0
        \else
            \end{scope}
        \fi
        \stepcounter{marknumber}    
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

it's not clear what your question is (I guess it's in the title, isn't it?).
I guess you wnat to *add* horizontal error bars, that is: in addition to the vertical ones that already are in the plot.

I think that the following might be what you are looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
x dir=both,x explicit relative,
y dir=both,y explicit relative,
]
table[x=x,y=y,x error=xerror,y error=yerror]
{
x      y        xerror  yerror
32     32       0       0.1
64     64       0       0.5
128    128      0.3     0.25
1024   1024     0.2     0.12
32068  32068    0.6     0.4
64000  64000    0.6     0.26
128000 128000   0.6     0.16
};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can add both `x` and `y` error bars by using

```
\addplot+[error bars/.cd,
x dir=both,x explicit relative,
y dir=both,y explicit relative,
]
```

Otherwise, if you just want to switch the vertical error bars to horizontal ones, you can just simply write:

```
table[x=X,y=Y,x error=Z]
```